# Personality traits associated with finishing other people's sentences?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, emotion, personality

I read in a North American undergrad psychology textbook, that people who tend to finish another's sentences tend to be emotionally intense. I think "emotionally intense" is the wording that they used. The impression that was given is that the type of person tends to swing moods more often or to a larger degree; they're more emotional.

Can someone cite the study? And does anyone know any other traits of people who like to finish another's thoughts?

Comment: I doubt that any one could finish another's thoughts. Unless you hold that thoughts are synonymous with sentences, which I don't as there are no thoughts, only sentences.

Comment: @Dan D., I understand your argument and I considered this when I used the term "thoughts" to replace "sentences". I erred towards using the more general term "thought" in case there were cases that I did not consider, like nonverbal communication. If you have a better term to cover such things, please suggest it. Maybe messages? Expressions?

Comment: I have a friend that does this to me, he has just done it twice - hence me being here!!  he tries to finish with the words he thinks I'm going to say... I sit and watch his mouth trying to form the words he thinks are going to come out of my mouth... It is driving me nuts as I've only noticed this over the last few months and I've known him 10 years plus!!

Comment: I also experience this at work with a direct report. This is a newer associate who is in the learning phase of his position. His progress is not exactly where we would like it to be, though he's not failing as a whole. He has a tendency to finish or speak in sync with the person speaking to him. I believe it is in an attempt to convey that he "gets it" -- a way to reassure his trainer that he's understanding, yet we're finding this is not necessarily the case when it comes time to apply that knowledge. So in summary, I suppose I'm saying it can also be tied to insecurity?

Answer (score 1):

Several factors may influence a person to finish off other peopla's sentences.
- The person may be stressed (and some people stress more often than others, thus stress may cause some people to do this more often)
- ADHD is said to cause an impatience, making the clients finish off other people's sentences:
http://www.healthline.com/health/adult-adhd
- A person may have a lot of energy, spending a bit of this energy on finishing off other's sentences.
- The speaker and the listener might ble close to eachother, and know eachother very well, maybe the listener was "just thinking of just the same thing"..

Whether or not I can find sources on "emotionally intense" people doing this, depends on how one defines being "emotionally intense". You could probably call any of the above examples emotionally intense people...